# How to update histogram based on selection of points (Altair)?

Tags: python, altair

My goal is to update the histogram shown on the right side of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydbT3.jpg) based on the selection of points on the left side.
Initially the plot seems to be alright, however once a selection is made the histogram won't be redrawn (altair 3.2.0)

Does anybody know how to do this?

[image: hist should be updated upon selection of the points on the left]

below is the code to recreate the example:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import choice

dates = pd.date_range("1.1.2019", "2.28.2019")
np.random.seed(999)
Y = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, len(dates))
features = [choice(["a", "b", "c"]) for i in range(len(dates))]
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, "Y": Y, "features": features})

base = alt.Chart(df)
area_args = {"opacity": 0.3, "interpolate": "step"}
pts = alt.selection(type="interval", encodings=["x"])
points = (
    base.mark_circle()
    .encode(alt.X("dates:T"), alt.Y("Y:Q"), color="features:N")
    .add_selection(pts)
)

yscale = alt.Scale(domain=(0, 1))
right_hist = (
    base.mark_area(**area_args)
    .encode(
        alt.Y(
            "Y:Q", bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=20, extent=yscale.domain), stack=None, title=""
        ),
        alt.X("count()", stack=None, title=""),
        alt.Color("features:N"),
    )
    .transform_filter(pts)
)

(points | right_hist)
```

*edit1*: another image to clarify my point @jvp

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is wrong with the result of your code? I ran this code and the output seems to behave correctly.

Comment: Hi jakevdp! The histogram should take only points within the selection (grey) into account (see new image). The problem here is, that I don't know how to translate this into proper python/altair code. The snippet itself is a mere combination of various examples found on the respective altair website ;) I'm still new to altair.

Comment: So I saved the output to a separate html file, opened it in another tab and it worked! Not sure what's going on.

Comment: I suspect your frontend renderer (e.g. vega notebook extension for jupyter notebook, vega labextension for jupyterlab) is out of date. Depending on how you installed things, it may not be kept in sync with your Altair version. However, when you save a chart to HTML, it uses the newest Vega-Lite version directly. Update your frontend and it should work properly.

Comment: It could totally be that my setup is tainted. I will test this tomorrow on another machine and delete this question eventually. Thank you for your precious time jakevdp!

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the comments as an issue with the OPs setup and how the plots were rendered on their end.